# Uncaught TypeError: gridElement.style.setProerty is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, setpropertyactionlistener

I'm trying to set the style properties but I'm facing the following JS Error Uncaught TypeError: gridElement.style.setProerty is not a function

```
const CELL_GAP = 2;
const CELL_SIZE = 20;
const GRID_SIZE = 4;

export default class Grid {
  constructor(gridElement) {
    gridElement.style.setProerty("--grid-size", GRID_SIZE);
    gridElement.style.setProerty("--cell-gap", `${CELL_GAP}vmin`);
    gridElement.style.setProerty("--cell-size", `${CELL_SIZE}vmin`);
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a typo - Do you mean setProperty and not setProerty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo. Change `setProerty` to `setProperty` and you should be good to go.